# Xcode 1) Start and stay in landscape mode with swipe gesture 2) Play audio sound when image is tapped

Tags: xcode, landscape, gesture, swipe

I'm fairly new at programming and using Xcode for iPhone App design.  I wish to do the following:

1. Start and stay in landscape mode for a children's app.
2. Use swipe gestures to move from image to image.  One image per swipe.

My problem is this:

even when starting in landscape mode, and after a swipe, the iphone simulator rotates to portrait mode.

Any advice or comment is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define in shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: which modes you support.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

will handle both landscape modes.

Comment: Vincent: I found the answer.  In xcode 4.5, I go to .plist file and go to supported interface orientations.

Comment: Every view (in the storyboard) is connected to a view controller (the .m file).
In the code, often close to the viedDidLoad is placed, this function shall be 
placed.

This gives the advantage that you can specifically control the orientation of each view.

(Please mark as answered)

Comment: Answered #1 but still need answer to #2.  Thanks.

Comment: You have to trigger an IBAction via your button. In the function you can do anything. Like playing a sound, changing an image.